# Exponent $\sqrt{2^{1.00001}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem doing this math excercise

$\sqrt{2^{1-1.00001}}$

i know the rule is

$\sqrt{a^{m-n}}=\sqrt{a^m/a^n}$

For some reason I got stuck at $\sqrt{2^{1.00001}}$ which me nor any of my friends know how to solve this.If there's any kind of method to do this please reply. Thank you :)

Comment: Wait... so you are wanting to find the decimal value *by hand*?  It will be irrational, so you will have to satisfy yourself with approximations using taylor series, but that seems far beyond what you are wanting to do.  Are you wanting to just express this without the square root?  Then remember for positive real numbers $\sqrt{x}=x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and that $(a^b)^c=a^{(bc)}$

Comment: What's the question?  $\sqrt{2^{1-1.0001}} = \sqrt{2^{-.0001}}$ and ... why isn't that an acceptable answer?  What are you trying to get?

Comment: I think simplified as much as possible since the teacher didn't state the objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that you're having trouble doing this exercise, but you didn't state what you are supposed to do with this problem. So, I'm guessing that your goal is to get this expression simplified as much as possible. Here's what you can do with it:

$$
\sqrt{2^{1-1.00001}}=
\sqrt{2^{1-(1+0.00001)}}=
\sqrt{2^{1-1-0.00001}}=
\sqrt{2^{-0.00001}}=
\sqrt{2^{-\frac{1}{100000}}}=\\
\left(2^{-\frac{1}{100000}}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}=
2^{-\frac{1}{100000}\cdot \frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{100000\cdot 2}}}=
\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{200000}}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt[200000]{2}}
$$

Comment: That's the answer I not sure why teacher give this kind of weird excercise to the class,but oh well teachers are teachers :|

Comment: What did he tell you to do with this problem? What's your objective?

Comment: It's a fair question if the actual objective is stated.  But if the objective isn't stated it is not.

Comment: I rechecked the excercise with my friends book and it's confirmed it doesn't actually have an objective to this excercise so yeah i guess you have to simplified as much as possible.

Comment: That  can't be true. Doesn't it say something like "simplify the following expression" somewhere above the problem? And does your book have the solution to this exercise?

Comment: No, the teacher just wrote this excercise at the whiteboard then walk away without telling everyone what to do except he told us if we don't know how to do this excercise our next exam will be 0 that makes everyone in class freezed and panicked for 1mn  ,that's why everyone is so confuse to this excercise because no one have any idea what the objective my teacher wants.Even if it's the teacher's mistake for forgetting to put the excercise title we have to try figure this out in case everything bad happens.

Comment: And today math lesson is about lim->0 idk why he gave the excercise in the first place to be honest

Comment: Sounds kind of sketchy.

Comment: Yeah i know :/..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2^{1 - 1.00001} = 2^{-0.00001}$, and $0.0001 = \frac{1}{10,000}$.

Comment: Thank you so much and thanks for the editing very appreciated :D

Comment: @SkullboyBZ You're very welcome!